# Particular number is divisible by 11

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

> Let $\mathcal{N} \ $ be a natural number of the form $\mathcal{N}=\textrm{dcba}$ ($a$ being the number of units $b$ the tens digit $c$ the hundreds digit and $d$ the thousands digit).
>
> On what condition $\mathcal{N}$ it is divisible by  $11$ ?

**my attempt:**

note that
A number is divisible by 11 :

If you sum every second digit and then subtract all other digits and the answer is:

$0$, or  divisible by $11$

By Mr Bill Dubuque i'll try to answer it

indeed,

Our Goal is to show that :
$$ P: 11/ (d-c)+(b-a)  $$

$\textrm{P} \Longleftrightarrow(d-c)+(b-a)  \equiv 11 (\textrm{mod } ) $
or we have for $\ {\rm mod}\ 11\!:\ 10\equiv -1\,\Rightarrow\,10^2\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\,10^3\equiv -1,\ $ by the $ $ [Congruence Power Rule,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)

therefore $\ a + 10\,b + 10^2 c + 10^3 d \,\equiv\, a-b+c -d,\ $ by the $ $ [Congruence Sum, Product Rules.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)

Or $\,\ P(10)\equiv P(-1)\ $ for $\ P(x) = a + bx + cx^2\! + dx^3,\ $ by the $ $ [Polynomial Congruence Rule.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)

I'm still trying to complet the proof

Is there many ways to prove this and which one is the best and easy to see it ?

Comment: How did you get $(d-c)+(b-a) = 909$? Since $a,b,c,d$ are digits between $0$ and $9$, it is impossible for $(d-c)+(b-a)$ to be larger than $18$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $N = 1000d+100c+10b+a$ $= (1001d+99c+11b)+(-d+c-b+a)$ $= 11(91d+9c+b)-[(d-c)+(b-a)]$.

Hence, $N$ is a multiple of $11$ iff $(d-c)+(b-a)$ is also a multiple of $11$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ {\rm mod}\ 11\!:\ 10\equiv -1\,\Rightarrow\,10^2\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\,10^3\equiv -1,\ $ by the $ $ [Congruence Power Rule,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)

therefore $\ a + 10\,b + 10^2 c + 10^3 d \,\equiv\, a-b+c -d,\ $ by the $ $ [Congruence Sum, Product Rules.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)

Or $\,\ P(10)\equiv P(-1)\ $ for $\ P(x) = a + bx + cx^2\! + dx^3,\ $ by the $ $ [Polynomial Congruence Rule.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)

Comment: could you please be more clear ? make it more details

Comment: @Educ What is not clear to you?

Comment: In general for me i begin with the goal of proof what i want to prove after that i go step by step . Thanks a lot

Comment: @Educ $\ {\rm mod}\ 11\!:\  n =  \sum n_k 10^k = \color{#c00}{P(10)\equiv P(-1)} = \sum n_k (-1)^k.\,$ Therefore, in particular, $\tag*{}$ $\, n = \color{#c00}{P(10)}\equiv 0\iff \color{#c00}{P(-1)}\equiv 0,\ $ i.e. $\ 11\mid n \iff 11\mid P(-1) = n_0 - n_1 + n_2 - n_3 +\,\cdots  $ $\tag*{}$

Comment: @Educ Please tell me *precisely* what is not clear to you. Are you already familiar with congruences?

Comment: yes i do but  the problem i understand by details step by step not by hint sorry to distrub you

Comment: @Educ Do you understand the proof in the above comment? That's the proof that I hinted (except the comment does it for any number of digits, i.e. any degree polynomial $\,P(x)).\ \ $

Comment: @Educ I was in the process of answering in your latest question, but you deleted it. You should avoid doing that, since it wastes the time of those composing answers.

Comment: Now i see your proof Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Proof by induction.

$0$ satisfies the rule.

Create multiples of 11 by successively adding 11.

In the simplest case this adds 1 to both b and a, leaving $S = d -c + b - a$ unchanged.

Any carrying operations add 1 to a digit and subtract 10 from a digit to its right. These operations also preserve $S \, (\mod \,  11)$.