# Divisibility rule of 11

Tags: arithmetic

> Let $M$ be a natural number  with $n+1$ digits; represented by $M=a_{n}a_{n-1}\cdots a_{2}a_{1}a_{0}$
>
> Show  $M$ is divisible by $11$ if and only if
>
> $$(a_{0}+a_{2}+a_{4}+\ldots)-(a_{1}+a_{3}+a_{5}+\ldots)$$  is also a divisible by 11

- here is Solution  By Mr [Américo Tavares](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/752/am%C3%A9rico-tavares)

Let

$$M=a_{n}a_{n-1}\cdots a_{2}a_{1}a_{0}=a_{n}10^{n}+a_{n-1}10a^{n-1}+\cdots +a_{2}10^{2}+a_{1}10+a_{0}.$$

For $\mod 11$ we have $10^{0}\equiv 1,10^{1}\equiv 10,10^{2}\equiv 1$,
and if $n$ even

$$10^{n}\equiv 1;$$

if $n$ odd $$10^{n}\equiv 10.$$ Thus

$$a\equiv (a_{0}+a_{2}+a_{4}+\cdots )+10(a_{1}+a_{3}+a_{5}+\cdots )\pmod{11}.$$

Since $-10\equiv 1\pmod{11}$, we have $$10\equiv (-(-10))\equiv -1\pmod{11}$$ and

$$a\equiv (a_{0}+a_{2}+a_{4}+\cdots )-(a_{1}+a_{3}+a_{5}+\cdots )\pmod{11}.$$

Could we prove it by the Methods of :

- Mr. [Mr. JimmyK4542](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/155509/jimmyk4542)
- Mr [Bill Dubuque](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/242/bill-dubuque)

from here  [Particular number is divisible by 11](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/916408/particular-number-is-divisible-by-11/916415?noredirect=1#comment1893401_916415)

Or Is There another way to prove it ?

Comment: The proof above is ok. Why do you want another proof?

Comment: to see things from different view :)

Comment: $M$ has $n+1$ digits, right?

Comment: @mathlove  yes of course

Comment: @Educ But this is so simple that there is really only one point of view! Anything else is just going to be the same idea presented slightly differently ...

Comment: @almagest  i can't be sure for the moment until to see others ways

Comment: @Educ, Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328562/divisibility-criteria-for-7-11-13-17-19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the question stems from my use of (radix) *polynomials* in my linked answer. This does indeed yield a generalization of such divisibility tests. Let's examine the proof closely.

First, notice that the radix representation of an integer is a *polynomial* function of the radix (base), i.e. if $\,n\,$ has digits $\,n_k \cdots n_1 n_0\,$ in radix $\,b\,$ then this means that

$$n = n_k b^k + \cdots + n_1 b + n_0 = P(b),\ \ P(x) = n_k x^k +\cdots + n_1 x + n_0$$

The test is simply $\ b\!+\!1\mid P(b)\iff b\!+\!1\mid P(-1)\ $ since $\ {\rm mod}\,\ b\!+\!1\!:\ b\equiv -1\,\Rightarrow\, P(b)\equiv P(-1),\ $ by the [Polynomial Congruence Rule.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)  Therefore $\, P(b)\equiv 0\iff P(-1)\equiv 0,\  $ as claimed.

The proof works for *any polynomial* $\,P(x)\,$ with *integer* coefficients. As such, these tests for divisibility by the radix$\pm1$ (e.g. also casting out nines) may be viewed as special cases of the Polynomial Congruence Rule.

Answer (score 1):

$$10=11-1=11k-1 \\100=99+1=9(11)+1=11q+1\\1000=1001-1=11m-1\\10000=9999+1=11n+1\\\text{and so}\\M=a_{n}...a_{3}a_{2}a_{1}a_{0}=a_{0} +10a_{1}+100a_{2}+1000a_{3}+...=\\M=a_{0} +(11-1)a_{1}+(99+1)a_{2}+(1001-1)a_{3}+...=\\M=a_{0} +(-1)a_{1}+(1)a_{2}+(-1)a_{3}+...+11(1a_{1}-9a_{2}+99a_{3}....)=\\M=a_{0} +(-1)a_{1}+(1)a_{2}+(-1)a_{3}+...+11Q\\\text{now divide M by 11}\\M=(a_{0} +(-1)a_{1}+(1)a_{2}+(-1)a_{3}+...)+11Q =M'+11Q\\M/11\rightarrow M'
$$